# Trigger an action after selection of certain option from select2 dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using a Select2 dropdown. I want to trigger an event on selection of the `Patient` option. Right now it fires an event regardless which option is clicked.

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
    {!!($errors->has('name')) ? '<div class="form-group has-error">' : '<div class="form-group">'!!} 
    {{Form::label('based on', 'Based on:')}}<br>           
    {!! Form::select('type', ['' => 'Select type'] + ['0' => 'Image', '1' => 'Patient'], null, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'id' => 'type',  'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}
  </div>
</div>  
<div class="col-md-3" id="timeframe-div" style="display: none;">
  {!!($errors->has('name')) ? '<div class="form-group has-error">' : '<div class="form-group">'!!} 
  {{Form::label('based on', 'Timeframe:')}}<br>           
  {!! Form::select('timeframe', ['' => 'Select type'] + ['0' => 'Daily', '1' => 'Weekly', '2' => 'Monthly'], null, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'id' => 'timeframe',  'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}  
</div>
```

```js
$('#type').on("select2:selecting", function(e) { 
  $("#timeframe-div").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: For future reference when asking a question where the server side logic is not relevant, please just post the HTML output to the question, not any templating logic which creates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Select2 documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#event-data):

> When `select2:select` is triggered, data from the selection can be accessed via the params.data property:

As such, use this:

```
$('#type').on("select2:select", function(e) { 
  if (e.params.data.text === 'Patient')
    $("#id").css("display", "block");
});
```

Note that this is reading the `text` property of the data you provide to Select2. If required you can change this to use `id` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#type').change(function() {
  if($('#type option:selected').text() == 'Patient') {
   $("#timeframe-div").css("display", "block");
  }
});
```